# jQuery: Delete HTML AND unknown content/amount of plain-text between elements

Tags: jquery, regular-language

Given the following HTML:

```
<div class="date">
<span>
    <i class="far fa-user"></i>&nbsp;{Name}
    <i class="fas fa-link"></i>&nbsp; LINK
    <i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>&nbsp;{ReblogSource}
</span>
<span>
    <!--irrelevant content-->
</span>
</div>
```

How do I completely remove `<i class="far fa-user"></i>&nbsp;{Name}` when `{Name}` could be any (number of) plain-text characters? The `<span>` it appears in is the first child of `.date` (though there are many other instance of `<span>` on the page), and the string I want to remove is the first child of that. Based on [Christophe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024971), I thought I could try

```
var string = '/<i class="far fa-user"></i>.+<i class="fas fa-link"></i>/';
replace(string, '<i class="fas fa-link"></i>');
```

but evidently there's something wrong with that. I'm... rather bad at this language.

**+:** `{ReblogSource}` also becomes an unknown length/content string of plain text. `<i>` is FontAwesome. I would rather not have answers involve the second `<span>`, especially if it must be involved by exact content.

**++:** I see both answers work in the snippet, but for some strange reason, Tumblr doesn't want to make it work. I've attached a screenshot of my end of things [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KW4qn.png), but I have a feeling I'll need to troubleshoot on my own from here.

Answer (score 0):

How about using DOMParser instead? Select the span, then remove its first three child nodes (two text nodes and the `<i>`):

```js
const str = `<div class="date">
<span>
    <i class="far fa-user"></i>&nbsp;{Name}
    <i class="fas fa-link"></i>&nbsp; LINK
    <i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>&nbsp;{ReblogSource}
</span>
<span>
    <!--irrelevant content-->
</span>
</div>`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
const span = doc.querySelector('span');
span.childNodes[2].remove(); // text node
span.childNodes[1].remove(); // <i> tag
span.childNodes[0].remove(); // text node
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

Comment: I appreciate the comments you put beside the `childNodes` lines, but as a raw paste, this didn't seem to work. I suspect the issue might be how long the HTML on `constant` is (I saw way too many colors for it to have worked as a single object (? "quoted mass"; my terminology is rather imprecise), OR that `{ReblogSource}` and the entire second `<span>` as well as `{Name}` don't appear exactly like that on my page, but I don't know enough to say...

Comment: What do you mean, colors? single object?

Comment: Colors --> At least in Sublime Text 3, different words (e.g. `.class` and `#id`) will show up in different colors. I'm building a Tumblr website, and within `<script>` tags, things between quotes or apostrophes generally show up in gray text. Single object --> everything you defined `const` as.

Comment: I added a screenshot just now, but I think at this point, there's something else in the code preventing either answer from working when I try to plug it in. Time to go bug-hunting. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contents()` which includes text nodes and `each()` and break when you get to `.fa-link`

```js
$('.date span:first').contents().each(function() {
  const $el = $(this);
  if ($el.hasClass('fa-link')) {
    return false// breaks each loop
  }
  $el.remove();
});

console.log($('.date')[0].outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date">
  <span>
    <i class="far fa-user">fa-user</i>&nbsp;{Name}
    some extra text
    more extra text
    <i class="fas fa-link">fa-link</i>&nbsp; LINK
    <i class="fas fa-sync-alt">fa-sync-alt</i>&nbsp;{ReblogSource}
</span>
  <span>
    irrelevant content
</span>
</div>
```

If the source html is a string just insert it into a temporary element and do same thing

```
const str = `<div class="date">
<span>
    <i class="far fa-user"></i>&nbsp;{Name}
    <i class="fas fa-link"></i>&nbsp; LINK
    <i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>&nbsp;{ReblogSource}
</span>
<span>
    irrelevant content
</span>
</div>`

const $div = $('<div>').html(str)

$div.find('.date span:first').contents().each(function() {
  const $el = $(this);
  if ($el.hasClass('fa-link')) {
    return false // breaks loop
  }
  $el.remove();
});
console.log($div.html())
```

Comment: Similar to CertainPerformance's answer, I worry that the length of the "quoted HTML" `str` is defined as will break the function. Said HTML includes `{ReblogSource}` and the entire second `<span>` as well as `{Name}`; none of these appear exactly like that on my page. All I know about `{ReblogSource}` and `{Name}` is that they render as plain-text; it might be safest to quote the first 4 line of HTML or less.

Comment: This solution gets rid of everything before the `<i class="fas fa-link">`. Can see I added some extra text also and it is gone. Second span is still there, I uncommented irrelevant code so it displays

Comment: I don't see anything in your clarifications that changes any of this from working

Comment: I added a screenshot just now, but I think at this point, there's something else in the code preventing either answer from working when I try to plug it in. Time to go bug-hunting. Thank you for helping!